# Why won't this render?

Tags: java, 2d

here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*; 
    class g
    { 
        public static void main(String arg[]) 
        { 
            System.out.println("hello"); 
            Rectangle rec=new Rectangle(4,4); 
            Graphics2D.draw(rec); 
        }
    }
```

when i try to compile it i get this:

> non-static method draw(java.awt.Shape) cannot be referenced from a static context

this confuses me. Why does this happen? If Graphics2D is an abstract Class how can Graphics2D.draw(shape s) be non-static?

Comment: No. It is not a static method. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw(java.awt.Shape%29. Seriously, what kind of question is this? Do you trust your intuition more than both the compiler and the documentation?

Comment: Well, the error text says all that is necessary.

Comment: i misread the documentation actually, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Graphics2D.draw` was static, *where* would you expect the rectangle to be drawn? The top, left corner of your monitor? The currently active window? Inside a *new* window?

`Graphics2D.draw` is not static because there are *many* graphics contexts in which you could be drawing. Explain to us *where* you expect the rectangle to be drawn and we can help you obtain the appropriate `Graphics2D` object to suit your needs.

If you want to learn about graphics, you should be able to do something like this:

```
public class MyGraphicsFun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.add(
               new JComponent() {

                   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                       return new Dimension(800, 600);
                   }

                   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                       Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                       g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                       // Any other drawing you want...
                   }

               }
            );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Disclaimer: This code was written from memory, so it could have errors

Comment: Im trying to learn about graphics so i'm not sure what i want to do? Lets say my monitor for now. What are my options though?

Comment: @David: You can draw to the screen, you can draw to a window, you can draw to a particular component within a window (as my example does), you can draw to an in-memory buffer, you can draw to a file, you can draw to a X Windows session... Many options. :)

Comment: In order to get it to compile i had to add import javax.swing.*;   
import java.awt.*;  to the top and then when i run it i just get a grey window, is that all it was supposed to do? thanks for the code sample btw.

Comment: @David: Yeah, it only draws a grey window. But now, that window is your canvas. You can call methods on `g2` and they should appear in that window.

Comment: @David: Replace `// Any other drawing you want...` with your own code. For example, you can put `g2.draw(new Rectangle(4, 4));` there and it should draw a small rectangle. If that doesn't work, try a larger rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

Not in this javadocs:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Which one are you looking at?

Besides, why don't you believe the compiler?  What's the point of disagreeing if you'll never get it past the compiler?  Just do what it says and get on with it.

You sound like a lost soul.  Start with this:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html